# "Developer" option is not available under Settings menu. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am missing a Developer option under Settings menu. What do I need to do to make it appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In versions of Xcode prior to Xcode 6, you can connect the device to your computer over USB, open Xcode → Organizer and select Use for Development.

Use for Development was removed from Xcode in Xcode 6 and later. It is no longer possible to do this for devices using Xcode 6 or later, even with the Devices page (⇧⌘2).

Comment: I see no option "Use for Development" on that screen

Comment: Sure. This is what I see after navigating in XCode 6.2 to Window -> Organizer: http://i.imgur.com/Mw61lob.png

Comment: @Jonah Use for Development appears to have been removed alongside the introduction of the new Devices page (accessible through ⇧⌘2). (Sorry for the delay, missed the ping—feel free to ping me in [chat] as I do miss the occasional comment)

Comment: TotalForge's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I found that by powering off the device, and turning it back on while connected to the machine running Xcode 6.3, the Developer settings menu returned for my iOS 8.3 devices.

Comment: This is the solution as of May 2015. Tested with iOS 8.3 and XCode 6.3.1 on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 3):

Apple removed the device list from Organizer in Xcode 6. Try going to Window->Devices. You should see your attached device in the list and from there you can enable development.

Comment: How does this improve or differ from other answers?

Comment: The OP said he was opening Organizer. Devices are no longer displayed there in xcode. You can find your devices in the devices window. That's the difference.

Comment: Well explain that and give some idea of versions of Xcode

Comment: I made the edit based on your recommendation.

Comment: How do you enable development from the Devices window?