# Enable "Developer" inside the "Settings" app on iOS

Tags: ios, settings, development, xcode

Before Xcode 6 one could go to the Xcode Organizer window. Tap on the Devices tab. Select the connected device and click the "Use for Development" button. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135382/developer-option-is-not-available-under-settings-menu-why).

However with Xcode 6 there are no longer a `"Use for Development"` button. So how does one enable it?

## Update

My Devices window looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The devices tab is now a new screen. `Use for Development` no longer exists.

The option in Window → Devices or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>.

From that window you could enable devices for development by adding your provisioning profiles. Right click on device and select **Show Provisioning Profiles...**. It will appear a window where you can add your profiles.

After that you will be able to install your apps in that device.

Comment: Aha. Thats it. Thank you for answer + updated answer.

Comment: Where do I find my provisioning profile to add? I see tons of profiles in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`, but which one?

Answer (score 4):

We just need to run our application on the connected device using xcode.

I got it on on my iPhone 6 with iOS 9.2 version by running a demo application from Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks works with iOS 9.3.2 using Xcode 7.3.1. Just install a demo app using Xcode and the developer menu in the settings app will appear. Then you can just delete the demo app.